# Por qué cuando ejecuto mi INSERT INTO, me dice que tengo un conflicto con una de mis llaves foráneas?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create table Departamento(
    nroDepto varchar(4) primary key not null,
    nombreDepto varchar(15) not null,
    ciudad varchar(20) not null,
    director varchar(12) not null
)
go

create table Empleados (
    nDIEmp varchar(12) primary key not null,
    nomEmp varchar(40) not null,
    sexEmp char(1) not null check(sexEmp IN('M','F')),
    fecNac date not null,
    fecIncorporacion date not null,
    salEmp float not null,
    comis float not null,
    codSuc varchar(15) not null,
    jefeID varchar(12),
    cargoE varchar(15) not null,
    nroDepto  varchar(4) not null,

    constraint fk_Empl foreign key (jefeID) references Empleados,
    constraint fk_Dpto foreign key (nroDepto) references Departamento
)

alter table Departamento
add constraint fk_nroDepto foreign key (director) references Empleados


select*from Departamento
insert into Departamento values ('1000','GERENCIA','CALI','31.840.269'),
                                ('1500','PRODUCCION','CALI','16.211.383'),
                                ('2000','VENTAS','CALI','31.178.144'),
                                ('3000','INVESTIGACION','CALI','16.759.060'),
                                ('3500','MERCADEO','CALI','22.222.222'),
                                ('2100','VENTAS','POPAYAN','31.751.219'),
                                ('2200','VENTAS','BUGA','768.782'),
                                ('2300','VENTAS','CARTAGO','737.689'),
                                ('4000','MANTENIMIENTO','CALI','333.333.333'),
                                ('4100','MANTENIMIENTO','POPAYAN','888.888'),
                                ('4200','MANTENIMIENTO','BUGA','11.111.111'),
                                ('4300','MANTENIMIENTO','CARTAGO','444.444')
```

> ***Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 32
>       Instrucción INSERT en conflicto con la restricción FOREIGN KEY 'fk_nroDepto'. El conflicto ha aparecido en la base de datos 'master',
>   tabla 'dbo.Empleados', column 'nDIEmp'.
>       Se terminó la instrucción.***

Comment: Qué hace esta línea? `add constraint fk_nroDepto foreign key (director) references Empleados`

Comment: Me sirve para conectar ambas tablas, específicamente la columna director con el nDIEmp, compilo y no me permite agregar la información de into a mi tabla departamento.

Comment: No, no es eso lo que hace esa fila... tal vez esa era tu intención, pero no funciona para eso...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La constraint dice que para poder insertar departamentos, tienes que tener un director.

Mientras la constraint este activa, no es posible insertar un registro, salvo que exista en la tabla de empleados o sea null. Pero como la columna dice not null, entonces solo puedes insertar si existe el empleado.

Se puede deshabilitar la restricción check para insert y update.

```
alter table Departamento
nocheck constraint fk_nroDepto ;

insert into Departamento values ('1000','GERENCIA','CALI','31.840.269'),
                                ('1500','PRODUCCION','CALI','16.211.383'),
                                ('2000','VENTAS','CALI','31.178.144'),
                                ('3000','INVESTIGACION','CALI','16.759.060'),
                                ('3500','MERCADEO','CALI','22.222.222'),
                                ('2100','VENTAS','POPAYAN','31.751.219'),
                                ('2200','VENTAS','BUGA','768.782'),
                                ('2300','VENTAS','CARTAGO','737.689'),
                                ('4000','MANTENIMIENTO','CALI','333.333.333'),
                                ('4100','MANTENIMIENTO','POPAYAN','888.888'),
                                ('4200','MANTENIMIENTO','BUGA','11.111.111'),
                                ('4300','MANTENIMIENTO','CARTAGO','444.444');
```

> Después de deshabilitar las restricciones CHECK, las posteriores inserciones o actualizaciones de la columna no se validan con las condiciones de la restricción. Use esta opción si sabe que los nuevos datos infringirán la restricción existente o si la restricción solo se aplica a los datos que ya están en la base de datos.

[Deshabilitar restricciones](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/tables/disable-check-constraints-with-insert-and-update-statements?view=sql-server-ver15)

Después puedes volver a habilitarlas

```
insert into Departamento
 values ('4500','GERENCIA','CALI','55.555.555');


Mens. 547, Nivel 16, Estado 0, Línea 35 Instrucción INSERT en
conflicto con la restricción FOREIGN KEY 'fk_nroDepto'. El conflicto
ha aparecido en la base de datos 'xxxx', tabla 'dbo.Empleados', column
'nDIEmp'. Se terminó la instrucción.
```

**Nota:** En el error que has pegado se cita la base de datos master.

> ***Recomendaciones*** Cuando trabaje con la base de datos maestra , tenga en
>   cuenta las siguientes recomendaciones: Tenga siempre disponible una
>   copia de seguridad actualizada de la base de datos maestra . Haga una
>   copia de seguridad de la base de datos maestra lo antes posible
>   después de realizar las siguientes operaciones: Crear, modificar o
>   eliminar una base de datos Cambiar los valores de configuración del
>   servidor o de la base de datos Modificar o agregar las cuentas de
>   inicio de sesión **No cree objetos de usuario en maestra**. Si lo hace,
>   deberá realizar una copia de seguridad de la base de datos maestra con
>   más frecuencia. No establezca la opción TRUSTWORTHY en ON para la base
>   de datos maestra .

[Master](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/databases/master-database?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió!

Answer (score 0):

Este código:

`alter table Departamento
add constraint fk_nroDepto foreign key (director) references Empleados`

Lo que haces es decir que tu tabla `departamento`, en su campo `director`, debe llevar una clave que se encuentre en la tabla `Empleados`.
Como tu tabla `Empleados` está vacía, marca ese error.

Desde mi muy particular punto de vista, tu diseño no es correcto porque cada tabla tiene un campo que depende de un campo de la otra tabla.

Saludos!

Comment: O sea tendría que primero llenar mi tabla empleados y departamentos, para recién luego agregar los constraint externos?

Comment: Ah! ya entendí tu comentario. No creo que sea buena idea... ¿qué va a pasar cuando quieras agregar un nuevo registro? Volverás a tener este problema, y tendrías que borrar las restricciones, agregar los registros y volver a crear las restricciones. Replantea tu diseño, alguna tabla no está del todo bien y por eso tienes esta situación.

Comment: Quizás deba replantear mi tabla, es un ejercicio que encontré en internet y estoy tratando de entender la solución,  no me compila es parte, gracias, veré qué puedo mejorar.

Comment: Deberías marcarla como respuesta... al final resolví tu duda :-)

Comment: Es que no soluciona mi duda aún, esperaré un poco más, gracias!

Comment: ¿Por qué no soluciona tu duda? Si ejecutas tu código sin las líneas que te comento, corre sin problemas...

Comment: Es que en el ejercicio que encontré supuestamente sí compila, no entiendo por qué a mí no, ya llevo buen rato intentando.